# Html Navigation bar item only last item clickable and the rest cannot

Tags: html, css

My navigation bar cannot click any item except the last item. I have checked and follow the tutorial from youtube but unfortunately I checked code is same but not working at all please anyone got solution please share to me.

Here's My html

```
<html>
```

```
<title>UIA | Homepage</title>
<link href="Homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

```
<header>
<div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
    <img src = "Logo.png">
    </div>

    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class = "active"><a href="Homepage.html"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="Promotion.html"> Promotion </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Booking </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> SignIn </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> About </a></li>

    </ul>

</div>

<div class="title">
<h1>Ready for another adventure?</h1>
</div>

</header>
```

And here's my CSS.

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

header{
background-image:
linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), url(Homepage.jpg);
height:100vh;
background-position:center;
background-size: cover;

}

.main-nav{
float: right;
list-style: None;
margin-top: 30px;
}

 .main-nav li{

display: inline-block;
}

 .main-nav li a{

color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px 20px;
font-family: "Roboto", Sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
}

 .main-nav li.active a{
border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {

border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img{
width: 150px;
height: auto;
margin-top:10px;
float: left;
}


.row{
max-width: 1200px;
margin: auto;
}

.title{
position:absolute;
width: 1200px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
 }

h1{
color: white;
font-size: 60px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 255px;

}
```

So did I miss out something please advice me Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware that most of the menu's links are empty? `<a href="">`?

Comment: @KobyDouek Empty links still are clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you do not use `clearfix` on your floated element parent(similar issues will occur on all floated stuff if you don't use `clearfix`).
Add this to your `css` file:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

And add `clearfix` to parent of floated element, in this case to:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
```

I recommend reading these two(will come in handy in the future):
https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Just in case, here is a link to jsfiddle with solution to your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/mwgjycv4/1/

Comment: @RexYou Your welcome :)   
Mark it as a correct answer for others who have the same issue to find solution faster :)

Answer (score 3):

`.title` is overlapping the menu.

You can give the menu a higher `z-index` to ensure it is on top.

[Information about z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

**updated code below**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(Homepage.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: None;
  margin-top: 30px;
  /* added */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", Sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.main-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 255px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="Logo.png">
    </div>

    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="Homepage.html"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="Promotion.html"> Promotion </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> Booking </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> SignIn </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> About </a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="title">
    <h1>Ready for another adventure?</h1>
  </div>

</header>
```